# Haskell ncurses

Tags: haskell, terminal, ncurses

```
main :: IO()
main = runCurses $ do 
  setEcho False
  w <- defaultWindow
  canvas <- newWindow 19 19 0 0
  panel <- newPanel canvas
  updateWindow canvas $ do 
    drawString "Hello world!"
  render
  waitFor w (\ev -> ev == EventCharacter 'q' || ev == EventCharacter 'Q')

waitFor :: Window -> (Event -> Bool) -> Curses ()
waitFor w p = loop where
    loop = do
        ev <- getEvent w Nothing
        case ev of
            Nothing -> loop
            Just ev' -> unless (p ev') loop
```

Hello. It is a bit modified example of ncurses package.
Problem is that is do not display anything. In C API, as I remember, I have to refresh each window independently. But Haskell offer only `render`. Where I am wrong? I want to have some moveable widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just to call `refreshPanels`.

Comment: Where does that function come from? I don't see a single word about it in UI.NCurses library and GHCi's `:i` option also knows nothing about it...

Comment: I think the OP meant `refreshPanels` in UI.NCurses.Panel.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.1.0.2/docs/UI-NCurses-Panel.html

Comment: @joom if you think that the answer is wrong (for whatever reason, be it typo or something else) - downvote this one and post a correct one.